# chrome getting new Error during WebSocket handshake

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, websocket

have node.js websockets running through haproxy, and has been running successfully for several months.

now now giving error

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Connection' header value is not 'Upgrade'
```

same code / setup is still working on development computer

any ideas / suggestions more than appreciated!

firefox works ok!  chrome errors from main server, but works correctly local

Comment: Check your packets with WireShark of similar tool. It's possible that some proxy on the way to your staging/production server become (mis)configured and now corrupts websocket headers.

Answer (score 1):

There is something terribly concerning here with this error message. The "Connection" header value should not *be* "Upgrade" but should *contain* "Upgrade". "Connection" is an HTTP header field which is hop-by-hop and may contain multiple tokens, including Upgrade, but also a number of other ones. This is in RFC6455 page 17 :

> " 5. The request MUST contain an |Upgrade| header field whose value MUST include the "websocket" keyword."

So I think that something is wrong in the server software, or at least in the error message. You should definitely take a network capture to be sure.

Comment: thanks.  know more about problem, so resubmitting along with test page